# javascript: How to reference a class from event

Tags: javascript, events, reference, this

I have a class like this

```
var grid = function () {

    this.cell = null;

    this.loadImage = function () {

       var image = new Image();
       var object = this;

       image.src = "blah";

       $(image).load(function () { 
           object.cell = this;                    
       });
    }

    this.showImage = function () {
       alert(object.cell); // This should print [object Object] ... but it print null;
    }
}
```

The showImage function is called after the image called loaded from loadImage function.
Does anyone know why object.cell is null... I have reference to this object in loadImage.

Comment: You might not want to use "object" as a variable name in Javascript. Could come back to haunt you since that is a pre-existing entity in Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

`object` is undefined in `showImage`.

Comment: The reason for that is that it is defined in scope of `loadImage` and isn't available outside. Instead declare it in the body of the topmost function

Answer (score 1):

This is what I think you should be doing:

```
var grid = function () {

    this.cell = null;

    this.loadImage = function () {

        var image = new Image();

        image.addEventListener("load", (function (obj) { 
            return function () {
                obj.cell = this;                    
            };
        })(this));

        image.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg";

    }

    this.showImage = function () {
        alert(this.cell);
    }
}
```